Daily Motion Web SDK Reference not work setFullscreen
I used your api for embeded daily motion player in my project.
I encountered a problem with switching the player to full screen mode.
Please tell me, where I do wrong step for set full screen mode for embeded player
Documentation
Codepen
<!-- Please replace the library URL to include your unique Player library ID created with your account and accessed via the Dailymotion Studio or REST API -->

<script src="https://geo.dailymotion.com/libs/player.js"></script>

<div id="my-dailymotion-player">My Player placeholder</div>

<button id="button">Fullscreen</button>

 dailymotion
  .createPlayer('my-dailymotion-player', {
    playlist: 'x79dlo',
  })
  .then((player) => console.log(player))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  dailymotion.getPlayer().then((player) => {
    player.play();
    player.setFullscreen(true);
  });
});

